# LCD displays weird characters

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd

I have connected the LCD by the 3 wire method using the LiquidCrystal595 library+74HC595 register shift; sometimes "hello world" is displayed but other times the LCD displays weird characters.
How to solve this problem?

[image]

[image: The circuit]

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: I want to know how to solve this problem  ?

Comment: Could be a bad wire, breadboard connector or power issue. Add a capacitor on the power line to the 74595 (VCC/GND). The next step is to check the timing in the library.